# Can Chatter Field Tracking settings be enforced/packaged in an ISV product?

Tags: managed-package, isv, chatter-feed-tracking

In my managed package I have a custom object and I would like to enforce that Chatter field tracking is enabled for some of its fields. Can this be done and how? The custom object is a Project and I want all its followers be automatically be informed by standard Chatter means if its Status field changes.

When uploading my package I only saw the option to stop the installation when field tracking for the whole object is not enabled. But how can I details this with regards to which field should be tracked.

I found the sentence `Chatter feed tracking and history tracking are automatically packaged when a field is packaged.` in the [Salesforce docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_behavior.htm).
Is this for the object or the field?

Comment: There is an idea [Enable chatter feed tracking via package install](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GyjM) that is similar to your requirements. It is marked as delivered, but doesn't say how you go about it.

Comment: I will just try. Maybe you want to convert your comment to an answer, so I can mark it later as "the one and only" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

There is an idea [Enable chatter feed tracking via package install](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GyjM) that is similar to your requirements. It is marked as delivered, but doesn't say how you go about it.

I suspect as you found this lines up with the Salesforce Docs for [Special Behavior of Components in Packages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_behavior.htm).

> **Custom Fields**
>   * Chatter feed tracking and history tracking are automatically packaged when a field is packaged.

I've seen comments that this automatic packing may only occur if the field is being added to the managed package and doesn't already exist in the target Org. E.g. It might not work as expected when doing an in place upgrade.